# Matlab Bootstrap not complete resampling

Tags: matlab, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to perform bootstrap in Matlab. I have 100 original data points and I would like each iteration of bootstrap to choose only 57 points with replacement randomly. How do I accomplish it?

I cannot seem to find this functionality in Matlab function `bootstrp`.

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

To choose `n` points out of a vector randomly with replacement: use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate the (possibly repeated) indices:

```
vector = (1:100).^2; %// example data
n = 57;
ind = randi(numel(vector),1,n); %// n random integers between 1 and numel(vector)
sample = vector(ind);
```

To do it directly with `bootstrp`: let `fun` denote the function you would pass to `bootstrp`. You just need to pick the first 57 values of each 100-value sample:

```
vector = (1:100).^2; %// example data
n = 57;
nboot = 10;
bootstrp(nboot, @(x) fun(x(1:57)), vector)
```

Comment: Thank you, Luis! I also found function (randsample, datasample) that allow resampling with replacement. Too bad functionality is not built into bootstrp.

Comment: @user1700890 I've never used `bootstrp`, but it would appear it can be done, as long as you incorporate the reduction of values per sample (from 100 to 57) within the funcion you pass to `bootstrp`. For example, try `bootstrp(3,@(x) x(1:5), 1:10)`. That gives me 3 rows with 5 elements each, sampled with repetition from `1:10`. See edited answer